# Date recognition fails with strptime and parse_date_time, don't know why

Tags: r, date

I'm trying to parse some log files into a more structured dataset. However, I'm having problems parsing some of the time stamps, but not all. Oddly, they have the same format, so can't find the source of the problem.

Libraries:

```
library(stringr);library(lubridate)
```

## base-r's `strptime`

First I used **base-r**'s `strptime`, but I ran into a peculiar problem. Despite being explicitly given the time zone, it still goes missing for some strings. Consider:

```
> strptime("31/Mar/2013:01:57:20", format = "%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S", tz = "")
[1] "2013-03-31 01:57:20 CET"
> strptime("31/Mar/2013:02:01:41", format = "%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S", tz = "")
[1] "2013-03-31 02:01:41"
```

Note how the first has CET, the other is missing it. Since I don't need time zones for my purpose, it wouldn't matter if it wasn't because this leads to problems further down the line when formatting the date. For instance, if one checks whether the datapoint is missing:

```
> strptime("31/Mar/2013:01:57:20", format = "%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S", tz = "") %>% is.na
[1] FALSE
> strptime("31/Mar/2013:02:01:41", format = "%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S", tz = "") %>% is.na
[1] TRUE
```

After scratching my head for some time, I gave up and tried another library.

## lubridate's `parse_date_time`

**Lubridate** is meant as a replacement to the **base-r** solution with a more user-friendly interface. Does it fail with the same strings?

```
> parse_date_time("31/Mar/2013:01:57:20", orders = "%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S")
[1] "2013-03-31 01:57:20 UTC"
> parse_date_time("31/Mar/2013:01:57:20", orders = "%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S") %>% is.na
[1] FALSE
> parse_date_time("31/Mar/2013:02:01:41", orders = "%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S")
[1] "2013-03-31 02:01:41 UTC"
> parse_date_time("31/Mar/2013:02:01:41", orders = "%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S") %>% is.na
[1] FALSE
```

No errors.

However, the above string is not the only one causing problems. These two strings are in the same format as far as I can tell, but one fails and the other does not:

```
#base
#works
strptime("31/Dec/2012:06:20:10", format = "%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S")

#doesn't
strptime("01/May/2013:00:01:37", format = "%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S")

#lubridate
#works
parse_date_time("31/Dec/2012:06:20:10", orders = "dbYHMS")
parse_date_time("31/Dec/2012:06:20:10", orders = "d!/b/Y:H!:M!:S!")

#doesn't
parse_date_time("01/May/2013:00:01:37", orders = "dbYHMS")
parse_date_time("01/May/2013:00:01:37", orders = "d!/b/Y:H!:M!:S!")
```

`strptime` just returns `NA`, while `parse_date_time` returns:

```
[1] NA
Warning message:
All formats failed to parse. No formats found.
```

The only difference I can think of is that May is bath a 3 letter abbreviation of the month's name and also the full name. However, telling it to use full names (`B` instead of `b`) does not work either:

```
> parse_date_time("01/May/2013:00:01:37", orders = "dBYHMS")
[1] NA
Warning message:
All formats failed to parse. No formats found. 
> parse_date_time("01/May/2013:00:01:37", orders = "d!/B/Y:H!:M!:S!")
[1] NA
Warning message:
All formats failed to parse. No formats found.
```

How do I get strings like the above to parse correctly?

Comment: Since Dirk abused his admin powers to force close the question, I cannot supply the answer. The answer is that the month names are loaded from the OS settings. My system is in Danish, so the month names are slightly different. It just so happens that the abbreviations are only different for May and October ("May" vs. "Maj" and "Oct" vs. "Okt"), hence why only these months fail to get parsed. E.g. `strptime("01/Maj/2013:00:01:37", format = "%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S")` works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You are starting from a very bad (but easy to make, we've all been there) assumption:

> Since I don't need time zones for my purpose, it wouldn't matter if it wasn't because this leads to problems further down the line when formatting the date.

I disagree and *strongly recommend* setting a TZ as you need for to reflect daylight savings. Just printing to the console involves formatting which in turn depends on having a TZ set.

Witness what happens on my box (sitting in the Central timezone):

```
R> strptime("31/Mar/2013:01:57:20", format = "%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S", tz = "")
[1] "2013-03-31 01:57:20 CDT"
R> strptime("31/Mar/2013:02:01:41", format = "%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S", tz = "")
[1] "2013-03-31 02:01:41 CDT"
R>
```

Furthermore:

```
R> is.na(strptime("31/Mar/2013:01:57:20", format = "%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S", tz = ""))
[1] FALSE
R> is.na(strptime("31/Mar/2013:02:01:41", format = "%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S", tz = ""))
[1] FALSE
R>
```

No need for new-fangled things like `%>%` or fancy packages wrapping base functions.  You need to get the basics right, or else the fancy wrappers can't rescue you either.

*Edit:* There is something else going on at your end. The parsing is all fine.  Here is the same set explicitly unsetting TZ:

```
edd@bud:~$ TZ="" r -e 'print(strptime("31/Mar/2013:01:57:20", format = "%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S", tz = ""))'
[1] "2013-03-31 01:57:20 UTC"
edd@bud:~$ TZ="" r -e 'print(strptime("31/Mar/2013:02:01:41", format = "%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S", tz = ""))'
[1] "2013-03-31 02:01:41 UTC"
edd@bud:~$ TZ="" r -e 'print(as.numeric(strptime("31/Mar/2013:02:01:41", format = "%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S", tz = "")))'
[1] 1364695301
edd@bud:~$ TZ="" r -e 'print(as.numeric(strptime("31/Mar/2013:01:57:20", format = "%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S", tz = "")))'
[1] 1364695040
edd@bud:~$
```

*Edit 2:* For completeness, it all works when setting your TZ

```
edd@bud:~$ TZ="CET" r -e 'print(strptime("31/Mar/2013:01:57:20", format = "%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S", tz = ""))'
[1] "2013-03-31 01:57:20 CET"
edd@bud:~$ TZ="CET" r -e 'print(strptime("31/Mar/2013:02:01:41", format = "%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S", tz = ""))'
[1] "2013-03-31 02:01:41 CEST"
edd@bud:~$
```

And yes, this will be the same with either `Rscript` or `R` but I happen to use [littler](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/littler.html) a lot on the command-line.

Comment: TZs are irrelevant for this question and I did not make use of 'my assumption' since I explicitly set the TZ.`%>%` makes for easier to read code. Could you instead address the question about why the parsing fails?

Comment: Be careful.  As I said, TZ enters as soon as you invoke the (implicit) `print()` that happens when you print to screen.  If you **really** want to compare without you need to compare the _numeric_ value converted from `POSIXct`.  As for `%>%` let's just agree to disagree.   Finally, do understand that my second example does *not* show the `is.na()` fail you had.

Comment: Then please edit the answer to make that obvious, I did not notice it and I'm sure others will miss it too. There is no need for arrogant ranting in answers. ;)